# Как работает fromkeys python?

Tags: python, словари

Разбираю я одну задачу в python, а именно удаление дубликатов из списка. Решение словно я нашел, однако не могу разобраться, как оно работает. Можете объяснить данный код, правильно я понимаю, что списки в python не могут иметь дубликатов и метод `fromkeys` автоматически удаляет дубликаты?

```py
list_of_numbers = [22, 3,5,2,8,2,-23, 8,23,5]
list_of_numbers = list(dict.fromkeys(list_of_numbers))
print(list_of_numbers)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу того как работает `fromkeys` вам ответ дали. Но, чтобы убрать дубликаты из списка можно вопспользоваться типом данных `set`, который имеет только уникальные значения в наборе.

```py
list_of_numbers = [22, 3,5,2,8,2,-23, 8,23,5]
list_of_numbers = list(set(list_of_numbers))
print(list_of_numbers)

# OUT
# [2, 3, 5, 8, -23, 22, 23]
```

Вы преобразуете список к типу `set`, а потом обратно в `list`

Comment: спасибо вам большое)

Comment: @ShaunMurphy на здоровье

Answer (score 5):

Списки могут иметь дубликаты. А вот словари не могут. Эту особенность словарей Вы и используете для удаления дубликатов.

[`fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) — это не просто метод, это *метод класса*. Он принимает итерируемый объект, содержащий ключи, и возвращает новый объект словаря. То есть после его вызова Вы получите:

```py
{22: None, 3: None, 5: None, 2: None, 8: None, -23: None, 23: None}
```

Так как это уже словарь, дубликатов в нём нет. И Вы преобразуете его обратно в список (через конструктор [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list)). В качестве элементов списка будут использованы ключи словаря:

```py
[22, 3, 5, 2, 8, -23, 23]
```

---

Кстати, дубликатов также не имеет множество ([`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set)), поэтому можно упростить Ваш код так:

```py
list_of_numbers = [*{*list_of_numbers}]  # list(set(list_of_numbers))
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, теперь я знаю три способа удалить дубли из списка.

Comment: спасибо вам большое за хорошее объяснение)

Answer (score 1):

```
list_of_numbers = [22, 3,5,2,8,2,-23, 8,23,5]
without_dublicate = list(set(list_of_numbers))
print(without_dublicate)
```